# Weird yellow bar pops-up: 'Microsoft Data Access - Remote Data Services

Tags: security, internet-explorer-7

When I access my site from any computer, I see this warning popping up:

> "This web site wants to run the following add-on: 'Microsoft Data
>   Access - Remote Data Services Dat...' from 'Microsoft Corporation'. If
>   you trust the web site and the add-on and want to allow it to run,
>   click here..."

I am guessing this is some kind of virus or something. I would like to know how to remove this from my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id be very concerned if this is on your own server.

I found the following blog post that warns on the issue: http://msmvps.com/blogs/hostsnews/archive/2007/09/13/can-you-spot-the-fake.aspx but doesn't provide any way of removing it.

I'd recommend making sure both the server and the client are up to date on Windows Updates, and then installing a good virus scanner.